# remove numbers from level 3 headers

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have the following YAML header: I have set section numbers done automatically

```
---
title: "some tests"
output:
  html_document:
    number_sections: yes
    theme: journal
---
# level 1
```

Then I have a level 2 header and a code that create tabs automatically:

````
## level 2 {.tabset .tabset-pills}

```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

for (h in 1:3){
  cat("###", h, '<br>', '\n\n')

  cat( '\n\n')
}
```
````

However, I want to make the tabs not numbered. I tried to set the level 2 header unnumbered {.unnumbered} but it does not remove numbering from level 3 headers.
and adding {.unnumbered}  into line : `cat("###", h, '{.unnumbered}', '<br>', '\n\n')` does not solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by replacing '{.unnumbered}', '
' with just {-} , but i do not have an explanation why 
    cat("###", h,'{-}',  '\n\n')

I anyone can explain why cat("###", h,'{.unnumbered}',  '\n\n') not working?

Comment: Even though you are answering your own question your answer should provide an explanation of why this worked.

Comment: not sure, although '{-}' is equivalent to {.unnumbered}, both do not act the same way